# How to translate "signifier"

Tags: traducción

If A and I function as "signifiers" of a certain abstract concept, how shall I translate "signifier"?  I was thinking:

> A y yo damos significado a tal concepto

Is there a more specific translation used in the social sciences?

Is it maybe a little clearer with "simbólico":

> A y yo damos significado simbólico a tal concepto

*Signifier* means

> a symbol, sound, or image (as a word) that represents an underlying concept or meaning (Merriam Webster)

Comment: Señal sounds more appropriate to me.

Comment: @Paul - How would I use that in the sentence?

Comment: *A y I funcionan como señales de cierto concepto abstracto.*

Comment: @aparente001 I think I understand that a bit better. Could you give a full sentence or the sentence before/after so I can make sure I'm giving you the best choice?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "signifier"? It isn't a very common word in English. Are you using it as it is used in [linguistic jargon](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/signifier)?  Perhaps an actual example of the word in English would help. In any case, as a native speaker of English I honestly have no idea what you're using the word *signifier* to mean here.

Answer (score 6):

Generally in terms of a noun, you'd be looking at a **significante** (which often is paired with *significado*, or the *signified*)

It sounds a bit odd in the structure of the sentence you have, though.  I would rewrite it as such:

> A y B son los *significantes* de tal concepto.

If you want to retain the structure (and you're not doing a signifier/signified-type relationship), you could say something like

> A y B *<sup>significan</sup>/<sub>representan</sub>* tal concepto.
>   A y B *<sup>simbolizan</sup>/<sub>designan</sub>* tal concepto.
>   A y B *<sup>encarnan</sup>/<sub>personifican</sub>* tal concepto. <sub>(more commonly when A/B are animate)</sub>
>   A y B *son* un símbolo para tal concepto.

Comment: The way it is in the original is kind of like "A and I give meaning to ___ concept."